# How do i put ana arraylist into an array in another class?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, arraylist

Im trying to put array list (linep) and (indexP) into arrays (vertices) and (pIndex)and the i need to render the line in opengl ....most likly a call to the on drawframe()? Im not sure how to do this i keep getting errors like the nullpointerexception for the array list ect... ?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
public ArrayList<Short> indexP = new ArrayList<Short>();
public ArrayList<Float> linep = new ArrayList<Float>();
public Float coords = (float) 0;
public short p = 0;
public int l = 0;
GLSurfaceView ourSurface;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cad);
    ourSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    FrameLayout v = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.display);
    v.addView(ourSurface);
    ourSurface.setRenderer(new GLRenderer());


    Button line = (Button) findViewById(R.id.line);
    final Button enter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter);
    EditText cl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cl);
    final String value = cl.getText().toString();

    try {
        coords = Float.parseFloat(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {};

    line.setOnClickListener(this);
    enter.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    Object pIndex =null;
    Object vertices = null;
    TextView info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.line:
        info.setText("Input X");
    case R.id.enter:
        switch (l) {
        case (0):
            linep.add(coords);
            l++;
            info.setText("Input Y");
            break;
        case (1):
            linep.add(coords);
            indexP.add(p);
            l = 0;
            p++;
            linep.toArray(vertices);
            indexP.toArray(pIndex);
            break;
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

```
public class Object {

 public float vertices []={};//  this is the array for coords

    private float rgbaVals []={
            1,1,0,.5f,
            .25f,0,.85f,1,
            0,1,1,1
        };

    private FloatBuffer colorBuff;

    private FloatBuffer vertBuff;

    public short[] pIndex ={0,1,2};// this is the array for the drawing order

    private ShortBuffer pBuff;

    public Object(){
        ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
        bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertBuff = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        vertBuff.put(vertices);
        vertBuff.position(0);

        ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pIndex.length * 2);
        pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        pBuff = pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
        pBuff.put(pIndex);
        pBuff.position(0);

        ByteBuffer cBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(rgbaVals.length * 4);
        cBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        colorBuff = cBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        colorBuff.put(rgbaVals);
        colorBuff.position(0);
    }

    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
        gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuff);
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, pIndex.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, pBuff);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

}

```
public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {
private Object line;

public GLRenderer(){
    line = new Object();

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
    gl.glClearColor(.8f, 0f, .2f, 1f);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
}



@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);
    line.draw(gl);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = (float) width/height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 25);
}
```

}

```
06-07 23:07:01.552: W/dalvikvm(2056): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a961f8)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:514)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at com.example.linecad.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:67)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3540)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14167)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4586)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-07 23:07:01.568: E/AndroidRuntime(2056):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: i can post the last error i got.

Comment: Bug found, see my answer... Well, _this_ bug found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NPE you see is normal and is due to a misuse of `List`'s [`<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29): you pass a `null` reference to it as an argument.

You need to declare `vertices` as a `float[]`, not an `Object` (why did you did that?), `pIndex` as a `short[]` and do:

```
vertices = linep.toArray(new float[linep.size()]);
pIndex = indexP.toArray(new short[indexP.size()]);
```

This method is not straightforward and you should have a good, hard look at the Javadoc (link above). In short, the array passed as an argument serves two purposes:

- it is used as a *possible* container for the resulting array;
- as generics are discarded at runtime, it also serves as a type hint so that the result is cast to the correct type.

Comment: Ok then how do i get vertices[] to the object class for rendering?

Comment: That is the source of the NPE. However, I'm also trying to figure out what he wants to do because `vertices` and `pIndex` are local variables to the `onClick()` method.

Comment: I want the vertices[] and pIndex[] to be in the Object class so openGL can render the line. and the array lists was just an easy way for me to edit those arrays. so i thought hat i had to call vertices[] from the object class.

Comment: Oh yes, by the way: DO NOT CALL YOUR CLASSES `Object`!

Comment: @DakotaMiller as to how to get them to the XXX class, can't you pass them as constructor arguments, or via a setter or something?

Comment: @DakotaMiller provide an example of what?

Comment: yes i can sorry still new and learning here. i can use a setter and getter method to fix that problem.